# Does copy constructor need to copy mutexes?

Tags: java, mutex, copy-constructor

For instance,

```
public Foo{
    private Object mutex = new Object();
    private int bar;

    public Foo(Foo f){
        this.mutex = f.getMutex();
        this.bar = f.getBar();
    }

    public Object getMutex(){
        return mutex;
    }

    public void setBar(int bar){
        synchronized(mutex){
            this.bar = bar;
        }
    }

    public int getBar(){
        synchronized(mutex){
            return bar;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `f` (`f.getMutex()`) ?

Comment: Depends how you want the class to behave, but definitely make the mutex data member final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends - do you *want* the two objects to share a mutex (a shallow copy, really) or do you want them to be independent? In most cases I'd expect the latter, in which case you *wouldn't* want to copy the reference.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, should do all of the following:

1. Make the mutex `final`
2. Not copy the mutex
3. Lock on the original instance's mutex during copy.